# android: checkbox linking to string arrays

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox

i am making a quiz, with 4 types of questions (and hence 4 types of respective answers).
i have defined 4 separate arrays for the 4 types of questions, name them arrayA, arrayB, array C and array D in string.xml.

In the layout, there are 5 checkboxes, for user to choose: All, A, B, C, D. If user ticks A only, only type A questions would be stored to the "question_to_be_quized" (QTBQ) string array. Similarly, if user only choose B, B would be put to QTBQ. User can tick more than one option. If user ticks All, all 4 types would be put to QTBQ.

My question is: how to efficiently put the respective question array to the QTBQ? I can just think of the foolish way that if (checkboxA.isChecked) QTBQ.add array A, if (checkboxA.isChecked) and (checkboxB.is checkced) QTBQ.add both array A and B...but this way i have to list out all the combinations?

how to write out for (checkbox isChecked) QTBQ.add respective arrays?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the problem?

```
    ArrayList<String> qtbqList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cbxAll.isChecked()) { //first, were all items selected?
        qtbqList.add(arrA);
        qtbqList.add(arrB);
        qtbqList.add(arrC);
        qtbqList.add(arrD);
    } else { //if not then check individually
        if (cbxA.isChecked()) qtbqList.add(arrA);
        if (cbxB.isChecked()) qtbqList.add(arrB);
        if (cbxC.isChecked()) qtbqList.add(arrC);
        if (cbxD.isChecked()) qtbqList.add(arrD);
    }
```

I think you have to resort to using an arrayList, as opposed to an array, because you don't know the size of it before-hand. Personally i wouldn't even have the check-all checkbox. Or if i did, i'd make all the other checkboxes checked upon checking it.